# How do you install silverlight Floating windows into visual studio 2010

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0, silverlight-toolkit, silverlight-oob

Hi every one at stackoverflow, I've just recently downloaded the latest file for silverlight floatable windows and I'm not sure how to install it into visual studio 2010 (I'm a "newbie").
The project I'm undertaking at present is in silverlight 5 (vb). Is there anyone out there that can walk me through the process for installation.

Kind regards

Will.

Comment: You mean the Silverlight Toolkit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer was kindly given to me from Johnson - MSFT at the Silverlight Forum.

In windows Explorer, browse to the floating windows folder, right click the dll file, select properties and under the general tab select the allow button.

In visual studio open your Silverlight application project and select the project menu, select your application properties from the drop down menu, go to the reference tab, click the add button and then browse to the floating windows dll file and click ok.
Job Done!
Please see the code that was supplied with the answer as an example.

Private Sub Btn_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)

```
    Dim fw As New FloatableWindow()
    fw.Title = "Show Date Time"
    fw.Height = 200
    fw.MinHeight = 150
    fw.Width = 300
    fw.MinWidth = 250
    fw.Content = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime()
    fw.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```